# Cambiar formato de fechas en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date, formato

quisiera cambiarle el formato a la fecha que actualmente estoy capturando en un formato parecido a este:

"**2019/07/06 09:09:58 AM**".

Aqui les dejo un ejemplo de como estoy cambiando el formato a la fecha, pero ese formato no me serve.

**¿alguien me ayudaria por favor?**

```js
var fecha1 = new Date(2019, 07, 28);  
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' };
  
//sin formato
var fecha2 = new Date(2019, 07, 28);
//con formato
var fecha1 = fecha1.toLocaleDateString("es-ES", options) ;
 
$('#Fecha1').html(fecha1);
$('#Fecha2').html(fecha2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Fecha Con Formato</h4>
<p id='Fecha1'></p>
<h4>Fecha Sin Formato</h4>
<p id='Fecha2'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes indicar la fecha y hora que necesitas y a continuación formatearla en el javascript de la siguiente manera:

`let formatted_fecha1 = fecha1.getFullYear() + "-" + (fecha1.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + fecha1.getDate() + " " + fecha1.getHours() + ":" + fecha1.getMinutes() + ":" + fecha1.getSeconds()`

Adjunto enlace donde explica muy bien distintos formatos de fecha en javascript

https://codehandbook.org/javascript-date-format/

Espero que sea de ayuda para lo que necesita

Comment: ¿y tendría alguna idea de como colocar el "AM o PM"?

Comment: puedes crear una variable para eso de la siguiente forma : var ampm = fecha1.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am'; y concatenarla en el formatted_fecha1

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes hacer es usar la librería momentjs de JavaScript, muy útil para trabajar con fechas

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo Angabo, MomentJS es una buena manera para manipular las fechas. Aquí está como usarlo:

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/es.js" integrity="sha256-bETP3ndSBCorObibq37vsT+l/vwScuAc9LRJIQyb068=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

      var nuevaFecha = moment("2019-07-06 09:09:58", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format('YYYY/MM/DD, hh:mm:ss A');
      alert(nuevaFecha);

</script>
```

[Aquí está la documentación si necesitas convertir una fecha que ya existe de otro formato](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). Si posible, evita native JavaScript Date Objects (los objetos nativos de fechas de JavaScript, es decir `new Date()`), porque es muy difícil formatearlas. Básicamente, hay que usar `getFullYear()`, `getFullMonth()`, etc. para crear una cadena para usar como parámetro para MomentJS.